Do pymc distributions include a parameter similar to scipy's loc?
As a specific example, I am trying to use the Exponential distribution to model data with a lower boundary of 10. In scipy: stats.expon(scale=1,loc=10).
However, I cannot find anything similar in pymc. I did see that this feature request was marked closed, but I do not understand how/if it was implemented.
